# How to change the nvc file format to avi or mp4 format

Tags: video, video-conversion, format

I had a video project which i made in Nero. It is an pictures slideshow with the mp3 music in the background. The file extension for this project is .nvc, so how to convert this .nvc file to avi or any other video format. I had tried the software called "Total Video Converter", but it does worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.nvc` is a project file created by Nero. It has information on how all the pictures and music are arranged but not the video itself. You must *export* the project in order to save it as a video format of your choice (converters only convert between video formats; they do not export).

Simply open the project (the `.nvc` file), click Export, and follow the steps. More information is available on the [official support site](http://www.nero.com/enu/show-tutorial.php?tut=MjQ=).

Comment: Okzz i will check & update u